# How to allow the put method in tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat, web

I connect the http://localhost:9000/..... (use put method)

however, sever return the 403 forbidden.

I heared the 'put method' is disallow in tomcat.

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat DOES supports the put method. You just aren't overriding it in your servlet or controllers. Your call to PUT needs to be caught by a controller/servlet configured to handle that request. If you're using pure Java EE and not spring then simply use the code below inside your HttpServlet and connect that servelet to the url-pattern you are sending PUT to.

```
@Override
protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    //Your logic here will be executed every time a PUT request is called-->
}
```

**More Info Needed:** Your question needs more information. What are you doing inside your web application to catch requests? Are you only requesting JSPs with no servlets or controllers? Do you override doGET or doPost? Are you using some other framework like spring?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the servlet. You did not specify the rest of the URL, therefore its not possible to tell, which kind of servlet handled your request.

If it was a custom servlet that you have created, you should overwite the doPut(...) method. If it was the "default" servlet from Tomcat, Put mehtod is disabled, as you can see in [Tomcat-dir]/conf/web.xml:

```
<!--   readonly            Is this context "read only", so HTTP           -->
<!--                       commands like PUT and DELETE are               -->
<!--                       rejected?  [true]                              -->
```

The "readonly" attribute of servlets is set to true by default.